# Trouble changing images with a timer with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, timer

I am writing a website and I want to animate through various images on a timer. I have an array listing each of the images (as a number which is used to build the `filename`). The animation should go through those numbers and in turn change the image. This code is not working and any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I've improved the grammar of the question and added highlighting to the code. No code changes because the code is the crux of the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```html
<img id="myImg"  src=" http://old.ycombinator.com/images/yc500.gif" width ='100' height='100'/>
<script>
var myImages = [1, 2, 3, 5]
var img_index = 0;
var timer;
var imgId = "myImg";
// Bind the image onload event like this:
document.getElementById(imgId).onload = animate();
// Start animation
function animate() {
    me = document.getElementById(imgId);

    me.src = "coolimg." + myImages[img_index] + ".jpg"

    img_index++;

    if (img_index == myImages.length){
        img_index = 0;
    }

    timer = setTimeout(animate, 1000);
}

</script>
```